# Adding 5th Rabbit Listener causes Quartz Job to be stuck in blocked state

Tags: spring-boot, quartz-scheduler, spring-rabbit

I have a Spring Boot app which has 5 RabbitListener's.  I also have 2 Quartz Scheduler jobs that run at regular intervals.  when I start my Spring Boot app it seems the jobs run once but then stay in a Trigger state of BLOCKED and do not run again.  I am using Spring Boot 2.1.2 and Quartz 2.3.0. Can anyone advise?

I used to have 4 Rabbit Listeners and did not have this problem but adding a 5th one causes this to happen.  I have tried deleting existing Rabbit listener's so there are only 4 Rabbit listener's including my new one and the problem goes away.

Here is the Rabbit Listener I want to add:

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class MyListener
{
    @Autowired
    private MyProcess process;

    @RabbitListener(queues = "#{T(com.earthport.elm.amqp.RabbitBinding).LIQUIDITY_BALANCE_CREDITED.getQueue()}",
            containerFactory = "noDeadLetterRabbitListenerContainerFactory")
    public void onMessage(MyMessage message)
    {
        if (log.isDebugEnabled())
        {
            log.debug("Received message: {}", message);
        }

        try
        {
            process.run(message);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my listener container factory configuration:

```
    @Bean
    public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory(
            Jackson2JsonMessageConverter messageConverter,
            RetryAdviceChainFactory deadLetterRetryAdviceChainFactory)
    {
        final SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory cf = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
        cf.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        cf.setConcurrentConsumers(1);
        cf.setErrorHandler(defaultErrorHandler);
        cf.setAdviceChain(deadLetterRetryAdviceChainFactory.createDefaultRetryChain());
        cf.setChannelTransacted(true);
        cf.setTaskExecutor(taskExecutor);
        cf.setMessageConverter(messageConverter);
        cf.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
        return cf;
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory noDeadLetterRabbitListenerContainerFactory(
            Jackson2JsonMessageConverter messageConverter,
            RetryAdviceChainFactory loggingRetryAdviceChainFactory)
    {
        final SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory cf = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
        cf.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        cf.setConcurrentConsumers(1);
        cf.setErrorHandler(defaultErrorHandler);
        cf.setAdviceChain(loggingRetryAdviceChainFactory.createRetryChain(
                new NoBackOffPolicy(), new NeverRetryPolicy()));
        cf.setChannelTransacted(true);
        cf.setTaskExecutor(taskExecutor);
        cf.setMessageConverter(messageConverter);
        cf.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
        return cf;
    }
```

Here is my listener container factory configuration:

```
    @Bean
    public JobFactory jobFactory(ApplicationContext applicationContext)
    {
        AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory jobFactory = new AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory();
        jobFactory.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        return jobFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean(
            DataSource dataSource,
            JobFactory jobFactory,
            Executor taskExecutor,
            PlatformTransactionManager platformTransactionManager)
    {
        Properties quartzProperties = new Properties();

        quartzProperties.setProperty("org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName", "ELM-Scheduler");
        quartzProperties.setProperty("org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId", "AUTO");
        quartzProperties.setProperty("org.quartz.jobStore.class", "org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX");
        quartzProperties.setProperty("org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass", "org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate");
        quartzProperties.setProperty("org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties", "true");
        quartzProperties.setProperty("org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix", "QRTZ_");
        quartzProperties.setProperty("org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered", "true");

        SchedulerFactoryBean factory = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
        factory.setOverwriteExistingJobs(true);
        factory.setAutoStartup(true);
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
        factory.setJobFactory(jobFactory);
        factory.setTaskExecutor(taskExecutor);
        factory.setTransactionManager(platformTransactionManager);
        factory.setQuartzProperties(quartzProperties);

        if (jobs != null)
        {
            factory.setJobDetails(jobs.toArray(new JobDetail[jobs.size()]));
        }

        if (triggers != null && schedulerEnabled)
        {
            factory.setTriggers(triggers.toArray(new Trigger[triggers.size()]));
        }

        return factory;
    }


    @Bean
    public Scheduler scheduler(SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean)
    {
        return schedulerFactoryBean.getScheduler();
    }

    public static SimpleTriggerFactoryBean createTrigger(JobDetail jobDetail, long pollFrequencyMs, long startDelayMillis)
    {
        SimpleTriggerFactoryBean factoryBean = new SimpleTriggerFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setJobDetail(jobDetail);
        factoryBean.setStartDelay(startDelayMillis);
        factoryBean.setRepeatInterval(pollFrequencyMs);
        factoryBean.setRepeatCount(SimpleTrigger.REPEAT_INDEFINITELY);
        factoryBean.setMisfireInstruction(SimpleTrigger.MISFIRE_INSTRUCTION_RESCHEDULE_NEXT_WITH_REMAINING_COUNT);
        return factoryBean;
    }
```

Here is the shared TaskExcutor used in my Quartz and RabbitConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class AsyncConfig
{
    @Value("${executor.maxPoolSize:50}")
    private int maxPoolSize;

    @Value("${executor.maxQueueCapcity:500}")
    private int maxQueueCapacity;

    @Bean
    public Executor taskExecutor()
    {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(5);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(maxPoolSize);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(maxQueueCapacity);
        return executor;
    }
}
```

I expect my scheduled jobs to keep running at regular intervals.  When this works I can see in my QRTZ_TRIGGERS table the TRIGGER_STATE is not BLOCKED.  However adding my 5th listener this value becomes BLOCKED and stays there.

Comment: I seriously doubt they are related unless you are using a shared `TaskExecutor` with a limited number of threads. Show your listener container factory configuration.

Comment: I have just added the config the my question.  I have also included my Quarts configuration.

Comment: Also my Quartz config and Rabbit config are using the same TaskExecutor bean which I have added.

Comment: What is the `executor.maxPoolSize` property set to? If it's more than 5, I don't know why you wouldn't get more than 5 threads. Have you tried increasing the `corePoolSize`? Or, use a different executor for quartz. You can use a debugger to look at the task executor task queue.

Comment: The executor.maxPoolSize value is set to the default of 50.  I increased corePoolSize from 5 to 10 and this solved the issue.  Thank you.